# SQL Server : calculate column value based on value in previous row/id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have what I hope is a simple problem to solve, but one that is puzzling me. My table can be created with the below sql:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
     [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     [lang] varchar(13), 
     [TotalProjectCost] [decimal](16, 2)
);

INSERT INTO test ([lang], [TotalProjectCost])
VALUES
    ('en',  CAST(341412.00 AS Decimal(16, 2))),
    ('es-mx',  CAST(342.00 AS Decimal(16, 2))),
    ('en',  CAST(341412.00 AS Decimal(16, 2))),
    ('es-mx',  CAST(34.00 AS Decimal(16, 2))),
    ('en',  CAST(341412.00 AS Decimal(16, 2))),
    ('es-mx',  CAST(34.00 AS Decimal(16, 2)));
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

This is basically a currency conversion task (the costs in the es-mx row are arbitrary in this example). What I wish to do is update all the `TotalProjectCost` values of rows with lang of 'es-mx': for these rows, I wish to calculate the value as whatever the `TotalProjectCost` value is of the previous 'en' row * 15.8735.

The way my actual table is set up, values are always submitted in pairs (one en, one es-mx)...so odd Ids should always be en, even ones should always be es-mx. As you can see, there's probably tons of ways to approach this and maybe that's why it's hard for me to know where to start.

I was kinda getting somewhere with this select statement:

```
select * 
from test as table1
inner join test as table2 on table1.ID = (table2.ID + 1)
```

But I still fall short of actually getting to the Update that calculates the correct values.

I appreciate any thoughts on this! I've tried looking around for an example on the boards that somewhat matches my scenario, but they seem a bit more involved than what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Look for `LAG` or `LEAD` function

Comment: Sure, so in this example all the 'en' rows happen to be 341412. I want to multiply by 15.8735 to get 5419403.382

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LAG()` widow function in an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, LAG([TotalProjectCost]) OVER (ORDER BY [Id]) prev_cost 
  FROM test
)
UPDATE cte 
SET [TotalProjectCost] = 15.8735 * prev_cost
WHERE [lang] = 'es-mx'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=555bcb5fc10d61fb0d100306433f22b7).
Results:

```
> Id | lang  | TotalProjectCost
> -: | :---- | ---------------:
>  1 | en    |        341412.00
>  2 | es-mx |       5419403.38
>  3 | en    |        341412.00
>  4 | es-mx |       5419403.38
>  5 | en    |        341412.00
>  6 | es-mx |       5419403.38
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
update table1
   set [TotalProjectCost] = table2.[TotalProjectCost] * 15.8735
from test as table1
inner join test as table2 on table1.[ID] = (table2.[ID] + 1)
    and table2.[lang] = 'en'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.*,
       (case when t.lang = 'es-mx' then t2.TotalProjectCost * 15.8735
             else t.TotalProjectCost
        end) as imputed_TotalProjectCost
from t cross apply
     (select t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.lang = 'en' and t2.id <= t.id
      order by t2.id desc
     ) t2;
```

This can easily be incorporated into an update, if you want to change the data:

```
update t
    set t.TotalProjectCost = t2.TotalProjectCost * 15.8735
    from t cross apply
         (select t2.*
          from t t2
          where t2.lang = 'en' and t2.id <= t.id
          order by t2.id desc
         ) t2
    where t.lang = 'es-mx'
```